# Vertically Mirror an Image in Java

Tags: java, pixmap

I'm trying to vertically mirror a pixmap I have in Java; here's my code:

```
Dimension coords = pixmap.getSize();
for (int x = 0; x < coords.width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < coords.height; y++) {
        Color newest = pixmap.getColor(-x, y);
        pixmap.setColor(x, y, 
            new Color(newest.getRed(),
                      newest.getGreen(),
                      newest.getBlue()));
    }
}
```

"pixmap" is the parameter of this instance method, and it's essentially the image that's loaded up. Here's the run-time error I get when I attempt to flip the image:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!

Any tips? Thanks!

** **EDIT** **

I changed the code to this:

```
Dimension coords = pixmap.getSize();
for (int x = 0; x < coords.width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < coords.height; y++) {
        Color newest = pixmap.getColor(x, y);
        if (x < coords.width / 2) {
            pixmap.setColor(((((coords.width/2) - x) * 2) + x), y, 
            new Color(newest.getRed(),
                      newest.getGreen(),
                      newest.getBlue()));
        } else {
        pixmap.setColor((x - (((x - (coords.width/2)) * 2))), y, 
            new Color(newest.getRed(),
                      newest.getGreen(),
                      newest.getBlue()));
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm still getting the same out of bounds exception; not sure where I went wrong on this piece of code ^

Comment: So, `-100` is within the bounds of the image how?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh wow didn't think of that, I was simply thinking of coordinates and just trying to flip it over the y-axis. Any advice on how I could do that considering all x values from 0 to coords.width are positive?

Comment: `coords.width - x`? But you'd only want to do half the width. Remember, you got to swap the pixels

Answer (score 1):

Java is giving you an array out of bounds exception.  You are trying to access a pixel that does not exist within the given array size.

Color newest = pixmap.getColor(-x, y);

this is most likely what the problem is.
a pixmap is a 2 dimensional array. Although I am not familiar with the class it probably looks like this:

```
//or whatever your screen is
int pixels[900][900];
```

that being said, your code is trying to access a negative x value coordinate an array.

EDIT:

```
Dimension coords = pixmap.getSize();
for (int x = 0; x < coords.width; x++) {
for (int y = 0; y < coords.height; y++) {
    pixmap.setColor(x, y, 
        new Color(newest.getRed(),
                  newest.getGreen(),
                  newest.getBlue()));
}
   }
```

Im going to assume this code will draw an image, therefore

```
Dimension coords = pixmap.getSize();
for (int x = 0; x < coords.width; x++) {
for (int y = 0; y < coords.height; y++) {
    pixmap.setColor(coords.width-x, y, 
        new Color(newest.getRed(),
                  newest.getGreen(),
                  newest.getBlue()));
}
   }
```

should draw an image flipped on the x axis.  You can probably figure the rest out from here

Comment: I tried the coords.width - x but that unfortunately still gave me the same exception

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is use Graphics2D with a negative vertical scale to do the flipping for you... Note this has to be in conjunction with a translate (0, -height) to bring the image back into the middle.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg"));

    BufferedImage mirrored = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)mirrored.getGraphics();
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    transform.setToScale(1, -1);
    transform.translate(0, -image.getHeight());
    graphics.setTransform(transform);
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    ImageIO.write(mirrored, "jpg", new File("test-flipped.jpg"));
}
```

Comment: That's a great solution, and I would do that but unfortunately I'm limited to using what I have above for this particular assignment :/. Thanks anyway though!